# Testing UI with MsTest

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

With NUnit, I could use NUnitForms to test the UI.  It's massively cumbersome, but it gets the job done.

Is there something similar for MsTest for the version shipping in VS2008?

Comment: You'll probably want to look into the "Coded UI" tests in VS2k10.  I believe that with VS2k8, it only has UI tests for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2008 use white http://white.codeplex.com/